# Azure Not Returning uploded certificates

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ssl, certificate

I have uploaded Certificates thorough azure new portal while i am not getting these certificates back here is my code

```
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
        try
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }

        return certificates;
```

These are the certificates which I always get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upxOn.png)

Also i have follow this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Anybody know the reason why i am not getting all the certificates and why i am getting these certificates ?? please help

Comment: When you say not getting these certificates, do you mean while running the code in the local machine or are you remotely debugging the hosted application?

Comment: i am remotely debugging the application . instead of geeting all certificates i just received these 4 . and in the local enviorment i get all certificates which are install on my machine

Comment: Have you added the certificate in the Settings->Management Certificates section in the old portal?

Comment: yeah ! i have added through new portal app->SSL Certificates -> upload Certificates.. PS: these are also shown in old portal

Comment: The thing is where are these certificates coming from . i have no idea

Comment: The certificates are from the server where your Application (I assume its App Service) is hosted. Have you uploaded the certificate as per this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-api-management-certs/?

Comment: yeah ! i have tried on both

Comment: I have posted a code below. One change I notice is using StoreLocation.LocalMachine for StoreLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm using this function I had found somewhere and is working fine. If you have uploaded all the certificates properly, can you please try running this piece of code. I know it looks the same but you can't really tell.

```
private X509Certificate2 GetStoreCertificate(string thumbprint)
    {
        List<StoreLocation> locations = new List<StoreLocation> { StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreLocation.LocalMachine };

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("location: " + location.ToString());
            X509Store store = new X509Store("My", location);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try, store.Open...");
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                Console.WriteLine("store.Opened..." + store.Certificates.Count.ToString());

                foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate2 Thumbprint : " + cert.Thumbprint);
                }

                foreach (X509Certificate cert in store.Certificates)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate Thumbprint : " + cert.Issuer);
                }

                X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
                Console.WriteLine("Finding certificate.." + certificates.Count.ToString());
                if (certificates.Count == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Atleast one found!!!");
                    return certificates[0];
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("A Certificate with Thumbprint '{0}' could not be located.", thumbprint));
    }
```

Comment: i have a standard 1:small Subscription ? what plan do you have ??

Comment: You mean the App Service Plan. Yes I have multiple from Basic to Standard and I am sure it doesn't matter especially if you have a standard plan

Comment: i think there is no difference between your and mine code

Comment: yeah ! i have heard the client certification not works for basic and shared .

Comment: I do not agree. I'm using the same code in Basic and Standard plans with no issues. The code differences between your code and mine - I see the StoreLocation.LocalMachine change. If you tried that already with no luck then the issue might be in the certificate upload. I hope you also have added the Thumbprint in app settings in the new Portal with key "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"

Answer (score 1):

> instead of geeting all certificates i just received these 4, and in the local enviorment i get all certificates which are install on my machine

From my test, [the article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/) in your reply help us to use Certificates in Azure web app. However we only could query the certificates with the following conditions:

1) the certificate has been uploaded to Azure web app 
2) setting WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES in Azure portal with its value set to the certificate thumbprint

It is different with your test on your local machine because Azure web app run in sandbox. For more information about Azure web app sandbox, please refer to [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Comment: Yeah ! i already did what you mentioned and i am debugging the hosted application which is on azure